# Cannot connect Pentaho with Oracle

Tags: pentaho

I enter the DB info and hit the "test" button but nothing happens. I've placed ojdbc11/ojdbc8 in the lib folder. Trying Connection Type - Oracle and Access - Native(JDBC).I have Hostname, database, port number, and username/password from sql developer.

Thanks.

Expecting pop up window to appear

Comment: which version of pentaho are you using? and also the JDK (java version)

Comment: pdi-ce-9.4.0.0-343 and java version 8

Comment: Please upgrade the java version from java-8 to java-11. Some of the functionalities are known to be deprecated with version 8. Also, use the ojdbc11 only and do not use both.

Comment: still no response after downloading 11 and deleting the 8

Comment: Please open the pentaho spoon in debug mode (`SpoonDebug.sh`) and get the log that is being generated by the spoon when you are trying to connect to oracle. It could be a different issue. The logs of the debug mode will be stored as `SpoonDebug.txt`.